# Rounding off a decimal to 2 places

Tags: java, rounding

### Code

```
package Java.School.IX;
import java.util.*;

public class Invest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter principle - Rs ");
        double p = sc.nextDouble();
        //Interest for 1st yr - 
        double i1 = (p*3*5)/100;
        double a = Math.round(i1,2);
        System.out.println("Interest for 1st year is Rs " + a);
        //Interest for 2nd yr - 
        double p1 = p + i1;
        double i2 = (p1*3*5)/100; 
        System.out.println("Interest for 2nd year is Rs "+ i2); 
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

### Issue

I tried using `Math.round(double, noOfPlaces)`, but this code doesn't seem to be working. I need some guidance.

Pls help me to round of the decimal to 2 decimal places. How to fix this?

Comment: Please explain the output you got, and the output you expected.

Comment: Also read [ask] and do required research here on SO, e.g. search for `[java] round decimal 2 digits`.

Comment: Many a times, I get the interest as 18.593958...... (a number similar to this with long decimal numbers). So i wanna round it off to 2 decimal places. Like rounding of 18.34867 to just 18.35

Comment: By the way, for money matters you would be using `BigDecimal` rather than `double`. Floating-point types [trade away accuracy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) in exchange for faster performance.

Comment: 1) Where did you find `Math.round (double x, int p)`?  I know of `Math.round` that take 1 argument in `java.lang.Math`, but I don't know of a standard one that takes 2 arguments. 2) `Math.round (double x)` returns a `long` and `Math.round (float x)` returns an `int`. 3) `float` and `double` are not suitable for precise representations of decimal fractions. `double penny =0.01` won't be exactly 0.01.  Try converting 0.01 to binary and see what happens.

Comment: Our teacher had showed to us in BlueJ. But turns out it is not working in VS Code and my teacher is not gonna say it again

Comment: @Challenged  do you have documentation for `Math.round(double, noOfPlaces)` that you can share with us?

Comment: Sorry to say I don't have any docs for the specified function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

`Math.round()`

```java
double i = 2.3333;
System.out.println(Math.round(i*100) / 100);
```

`NumberFormat.format()`

```java
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");     
System.out.println(formatter.format(2.3333));
```

`System.out.printf()`

```java
System.out.printf("%.2f", 3.2222);
```

Probaly there are 10 more ways of doing it, thats just what I can think of right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class. It can format the number with exact number of digits past decimal point.

Comment: This could also been a comment with proper link. Please give a short code example to illustrate application to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't round the actual value.  Let [System.out.printf()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) do the work for you.

```
double [] data = {1.4452, 123.223,23.229};
for (double v : data) {
   System.out.printf("%.2f%n",v);
}
```

prints

```
1.45
123.22
23.23
```

Comment: Man why have you written "%.2f%n" ? What does it mean (I am a beginner in java. So asking its meaning)

Comment: That's why I posted a linke to the method. It says for %b.cf" allow b places to the left of the decimal and c to to the right.  It rounds half up.  if b or c are omitted, it allows any precision in that place.

Answer (score 0):

In favor for [Basil's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72418054/rounding-off-a-decimal-to-2-places#comment127931981_72418054):

- prefer `BigDecimal` for currency amounts

```
// I = PRT
// Returns: interest for n-th year for principal amount (also printed on stdout)
BigDecimal interestFor(BigDecimal principalAmount, int year) {
    BigDecimal interest = principalAmount.multiply(3*5).divide(100); // FIX:  check formula here to be correct on years!

    // Locale.US for $, but if we want Indian Rupee as: Rs
    Locale locale = new Locale("en", "IN");
    String interestFormatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(interest);
    
    System.out.printf("Interest for year %d is %s\n", year, interestFormatted);
    
    return interest;
}
```

For the placeholder literals `%s` (string formatted), `%d` (decimal formatted), see Java's [`Formatter` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

See also:

- [A realistic example where using BigDecimal for currency is strictly better than using double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871564/a-realistic-example-where-using-bigdecimal-for-currency-is-strictly-better-than)
- [How to print formatted BigDecimal values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395825/how-to-print-formatted-bigdecimal-values)