# Can Libgdx store very large numbers in its coordinate system?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to write game with a scientifically accurate solar system, and am trying to figure out the best way to use coordinates in a massive scale. When I read about the coordinate system in Libgdx it said it uses "Floating Point" to store the coordinate data.

I want to have centimeter accuracy going out to ~5.5 billion kilometers, that is 12 decimal places. I am afraid that the coordinates won't be accurate when this large.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: All of the Libgdx APIs I looked at use `float` rather than `double`.

Comment: @StephenC Would it be able to accurately store 12 decimal places?

Comment: If the APIs only support `float` then it is moot whether they "store" things with a greater precision.  (You do know what the precision of the Java `float` type is ... I assume.  If not, you should do some self-learning before you leap into this project.)

Comment: Are you sure about the 12 decimal places? 1 billion km = 10^9 km = 10^12 m = 10^14 cm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used the `libgdx` library, but looking at its [API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XXON.png) (for instance Vector3 or Rectangle), it seems it uses `float`s.

## Floats

Java's `float` represent numbers in binary scientific notation, that is, each number is represented by a 23-bit *significand* and an 8-bit *exponent*. Think of it as a form (like a transfer form at your bank, where you have to write how much money you would like to transfer). In each box you can write a `1` or `0`:
[image: float form]

Note: 23 + 8 = 31, the missing bit is used as the sign of the number. In this answer, we do not deal with negative numbers or negative exponents.

## Precision

Due to the exponent, floats get less precise for bigger numbers. Some examples:

```
 10_000_000 == 1E7 != 1E7 + 1 == 1.0000001E7 ==  10_000_001
100_000_000 == 1E8 == 1E8 + 1 == 1.0000000E8 == 100_000_000
```

At 10<sup>8</sup> the significand is not precise enough to represent a difference of 1.

Lets calculate the precision for your use case, where numbers don't get bigger than 5.5 billion kilometers measured in centimeters:

5.5 × 10<sup>9</sup> km = 5.5 × 10<sup>14</sup> cm = 1.11110100001110001101101 010100000011<sub>bin</sub> × 2<sup>48</sup> cm

Since we have only 23 bits to represent that number, it is approximated as

1.11110100001110001101101<sub>bin</sub> × 2<sup>48</sup> cm
= 549'999'989'489'664 cm
= 5'499'999'894'896.64 m = 5'499'999'894.896 64 km

You would be off by more than 100 km!

## Possible Workarounds

- Use another  library that uses `double` instead of `float`. Doubles have a 52-bit significand, which is precise enough for your use case.
- Use two `float`s for each position: A coarse position and a fine-grained offset (not recommended).
- Don't try to be that precise. I doubt that anyone can track objects in the outer solar systems centimeter-level precise.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you want to create [your own version of a Vector](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector.java) which uses `BigDecimal` since you can control the number of significands. The value of the number represented by the BigDecimal is therefore (unscaledValue × 10-scale), [see Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's good question to pops up interesting solution.

Your question tagged as `libgdx`, so my solution won't stay away from using it. Let's tackle into each issue here.

## No Matter, It's Still Float

Firstly, I need to tell you that no matter how precision of position (float, double) you have, libgdx's underlying system will go with `float` at the end. See its [SpriteBatch](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.java) class which use `float` to represent position whenever it needs to draw something on screen, and also `Sprite` class which bases things off `float` for its position as well.

This means no matter your precision, things will be drew on screen in `float`.

## Precision

Also no matter you use `float` or `double`, you will be getting **floating-point calculation error**. If you cannot be off by one bit (i don't know your game requirement deeply), whether it's about position or something else according to your game, then you might need to consider using [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Bank application would use something like this as it cannot lose any one bit due to rounding-error, customer would likely complain!

You might get away by maintaining `BigDecimal` inside your game object. You update its position through them instead of normal way to set position in libgdx. But whenever you need to draw, you get its value via [doubleValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue()). Why double and not float? It's better to get highest precision that it can offers to use for your game, so when floating-number cannot 100% accurately represents the number, you will get smallest error as less as possible.

## BigDecimal Is Slow

**Be careful** as `BigDecimal` is slower than normal floating-point operation. See its benchmarks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14733855/571227) and [here](https://gist.github.com/deepak/5353921).

## Workarounds

Because I see that at one point in time, users only see a limited area on your space. Or even if you might have a space map that allows user to zoom-out to see the whole area, that's a time when you don't really need precision or per-se `double`-precision, default way libgdx does is suffice and no need to switch game library (others will mostly base on `float` anyway) as well.

That's the reason that you can still use `float` but use `BigDecimal` or just `String` to represent any large scientific value on screen which doesn't involve in calculation that affects the game performance in run-time. Thus I believe this allows us to scale down the massive distance so you can represent game objects with same intention to be scientific correct.