# Odd result of a floating point computation in java

Tags: java, floating-point, computation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java floating point math - (conversion for feet/meters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611709/java-floating-point-math-conversion-for-feet-meters)
>   [Java floating point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/java-floating-point-arithmetic)

I am running into the following problem in java.

This computation (`0.196f * 100`) yields `19.599999487400055` instead of `19.6`.

I am puzzled. Can anyone please tell me why I get this odd result and how I can make sure I get the proper result without having to pollute my code with rounding all over the place.

Also what other jvm language deals with such problems better? Would scala be any different for example?

Comment: Again? We've had this question and a dozens slight variations a hundred times already.

Comment: You're using floating point numbers. Get used to inaccuracies. They're unavoidable.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: A better introductory text: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

As the comments already state, floating point numbers always suffer from inaccuracies. `double` suffers to a lesser extend but it still suffers from that, so you'll have to deal with them.

If you want exact calculations use `BigDecimal` although you can't use operators then.