# how to truncate an double datatype value variable

Tags: c#

i have  an class

```
public class Score
{
    public double  marks { get; set; }
}
```

now in my code

```
List<Level1> Obj= new List<Level1>();
 Score Object= new Score();
 l1.marks=94.345454;
Obj.Add(Object)
```

**// now  whiling  adding  the object to list  i need  to  trunacte the value to
94.34 and store in the list obj.**
 so that i need  to get  output has 94.34
  how  can i  do it.
 thanks in advance
 prince

Comment: you will receive compile time error for Level1 and Score type mismatch

Answer (score 2):

Keep the value as a double, and only format it on output.

```
string output = doubleValue.ToString("F2");
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).  As an example:

```
doubleNumber = -1898300.1987;
Console.WriteLine(doubleNumber.ToString("F1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));  
// Displays -1898300.2

Console.WriteLine(doubleNumber.ToString("F3", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES")));
// Displays -1898300,199
```

Notice the decimal comma on the last output as the culture is set to Spanish.

Comment: +1 I agree.  Keep the number at it's full precision internally and truncate on output, though this rounds instead of truncates.  I think that's also the correct behavior, but the OP asks for truncation.  See this answer for truncation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329957/truncate-decimal-number-not-round-off

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in the `marks` property setter:

```
value -= value % 0.01
```

this will subtract 0.005454 from `value` and so leave you with the correct number of decimal points (in this case, 2)

something like:

```
public class Score {
    private double m_marks;

    public double marks {
        get { return m_marks; }
        set { m_marks = value - (value % 0.01); }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is that as extension method for double?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Math.Round(number, precision) as shown on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx)