# how to take 6 numbers after the dot - but without round the number?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to take 6 numbers after the dot - but without round the number ?

for example:

`102.123456789  =>  102.123456`

```
9.99887766 => 9.998877
```

in C# winforms

thak's in advance

Comment: So you simply want to "chop" the number at the sixth decimal place rather than carrying out *any* form of rounding?

Comment: I would suggest [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx), but you state you want truncation not rounding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329957/truncate-decimal-number-not-round-off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.Math.Truncate (102.123456789 * factor) / factor;
```

In your case factor is 10^6; [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/whats-the-difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate-in-net)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`Math.Truncate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.truncate.aspx) method and a 10^6 multiplier:

```
decimal x = 102.12345689m;
decimal m = 1000000m;
decimal y = Math.Truncate(m * x) / m;
Console.WriteLine(y); // Prints 102.123456
```

Comment: That truncates to an integer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2eabd70.aspx "Truncate rounds d to the nearest integer towards zero."

Comment: @Chris: the code works.  He's using the 10^6 multiplier to work around that issue - actually fairly elegant, and much cleaner than using strings!

Comment: @Dan - The code was edited after @ChrisF downvoted, check the edits.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky - just to point out I didn't downvote, just commented. I like to give people chance to correct their posts first.

Comment: @Dan, I think that's because I deleted the answer, then edited and undeleted it.

Comment: @Thomas, can you just edit your answer then I can remove the down vote.  You are correct, I had downvoted the original answer and was in the process of adding a comment when you deleted your original answer.  I've just tried to remove down vote and it's telling me it's locked unless you edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
  public decimal TruncateDecimal(decimal decimalToTruncate, uint numberOfDecimalPlacse)
  {
     decimal multiplication_factor = (decimal)Math.Pow(10.0, numberOfDecimalPlacse);
     decimal truncated_value = (long)(multiplication_factor * decimalToTruncate);
     return (truncated_value / multiplication_factor);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ugly using strings, but thought I'd put it anyway:

```
double x = 9.9887766;
string[] xs = x.ToString().Split('.');
double result = double.Parse(xs[0] + "." + xs[1].Substring(0, Math.Min(xs[1].Length, 6)));
```

Comment: Similar to my solution but you've provided actual code.  If you go this route, you may want to check that xs[1] is not null first (calling sub string would through an exception).  Also for non null values, what happens if it contains less than 6 characters.

Comment: @Paul - Yeah I caught the 2nd part just before you replied. But yeah... this is a really crude example. If the OP wants to always check if `xs[1]` is null/non-existent then he can do so.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a long winded way, but how about turning it into a string, locating the decimal point and then grabbing the string minus anything after the 6th decimal place.  You could then turn it back into a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

It's crude but how about:

```
decimal Number = 102.123456789;
string TruncateTarget = Number.ToString();
decimal FinalValue = Decimal.Parse(TruncateTarget.Substring(0, TruncateTarget.IndexOf('.') +6));
```