# Have decimal amount, want to trim to 2 decimal places if present

Tags: c#, math, decimal

Have decimal amount, want to trim to 2 decimal places if present

Comment: Do you want to just "lop off the excess decimals" or do you want to round like Jon says?

Comment: Truncate or Round?  To Truncate see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329957/truncate-decimal-number-not-round-off

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you tried using `value = Decimal.Round(value, 2)`?

For example:

```
using System;

class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        decimal d = 1234.5678m;
        Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", d); // Prints 1234.5678
        d = decimal.Round(d, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("After: {0}", d); // Prints 1234.57
    }
}
```

Note that this is rounding rather than just trimming (so here it's rounded up)... what exactly do you need? Chances that the `Decimal` struct supports whatever you need to do. Consult [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) for more options.

Comment: Math.Round can do banker's rounding. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131275.aspx

Answer (score 12):

```
decimal.Truncate(myDecimal * 100) / 100
```

This would cut away everything following the first two decimal places. For rounding see Jon's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If its just for display purposes, you can use:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("Number is: {0:F2}", myDecimalNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this:
Math.Round(MyDecimalValue,2);

Answer (score 0):

This should work (EDIT: Fixed to remove rounding):

```
((Int32)(value * Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces))) / (Math.Pow(10D, decimalPlaces));
```

Comment: In C# `^` is `xor`. Also, if someone uses `decimal` chances are it's a deliberate choice and they probably don't want another type (apart from that your example is way off in any case).

Comment: Right, sorry should be math.exp (). How is it off otherwise?

Comment: `Int` is not a type in C# and you're doing integer division afterwards, leaving no decimal places anyway.