# Prevent Math.Round(95.55555555,2) from rounding to 95.56 in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

If I do `Math.Round(95.55555555,2)` in VB.NET, the result is `95.56`, but I want it the result the be `95.55`.  Is there a way to do this in VB.NET?  I guess I just want to keep the decimal places, but not round them

Comment: The question is: what is your precise condition to round it to 95.55 rather than 95.56? If it's only a question of limit at which point to round to the lesser rather than the greater, it's trivial to write your own rounding function, I think. I will not try it, as I'm not really fond of VB... :-) But be careful with border effects...

Comment: Would you want `Math.Round(95.55666666,2)` to round to 95.55 or 95.56?  Are you actually rounding or just cutting it off after x precision?

Comment: Sounds like you're not actually wanting a round, but rather a truncate.

Comment: Yes, I basically want to truncate, but keep two decimal places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like `Math.Truncate(95.5555555 * 100) / 100`. 
See [Truncate Decimal number not Round Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329957/truncate-decimal-number-not-round-off)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/whats-the-difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate-in-net

Answer (score 5):

Try using `Math.Floor(95.55555555 * 100) / 100`

Or, if you want to round to a specific number of decimals:

```
Public Function RoundDown(ByVal value As Double, ByVal decimalPlaces As Integer) As Double
    If (decimalPlaces < 1) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid decimalPlaces: less than 1")
    EndIf

    Dim factor As Integer = 10 ^ decimalPlaces
    Return Math.Floor(value * factor) / factor
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you talking about? `Floor(95.5555555... * 100) = 9555`, and `9555/100 = 95.55`.

Comment: One question I have is what if I wanted to truncate to 3 decimal places, how does that change the Math.Floor or Math.Truncate method.  For example, I want 95.5556 to be 95.555.

Comment: After looking at a similar question, is it just doing something like Math.Floor(value * 1000) / 1000; to keep 3 decimal places.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly how you would do it for 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this.  One would be to subtract 0.05 from the number then use `Math.Round(number, 2)`.  (This works on the same principle as implementing `floor` and `ceiling` functions when all you have is `round`.)

A better way is probably

```
Math.Truncate(number * 100) / 100
```

That just multiplies the number by 100 and truncates it, giving you an integer value with the digits you want, then divides by 100 to turn it back to a decimal.

Comment: What is the difference between Math.Floor(number * 100) /100 and Math.Truncate(number * 100) / 100?

Comment: Floor is used to round down. Truncate just cuts. Ceiling rounds up

Comment: @Xaisoft: Floor always rounds down, so you'll see a difference if your value is negative.

Comment: They are two different operations that return the same result, in this case. `Floor()` returns the closest integer value smaller than the input (but not necessarily `Integer` type), while `Truncate()` chops off everything after the decimal. *They are only different in how they handle negative numbers.*

Answer (score 1):

You don't want Math.Round. You want Math.Truncate.

```
Dim decimalNumber As Double = 95.55555555
Dim truncatedNumber As Double = Math.Truncate(decimalNumber * 100) / 100
```

Your result will be 95.55.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
static double TruncateWithDecimals(double n, int nOfDec)
        {
           return Math.Round(Math.Floor(n * Math.Pow(10, nOfDec)) /  Math.Pow(10, nOfDec), nOfDec);
        }
```

sorry this is C#, but you can easily guess how to translate in vb I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function Round(Number As Decimal, places As Integer) As Decimal
    'Convert number to string
    Dim NumberString As String = Number.ToString
    'Check if the number contains a decimal, if not return the number
    If NumberString.IndexOf("."c) = -1 Then Return Number
    'Get the whole number part of the string
    Dim IntegerPart As String = NumberString.Split("."c)(0)
    'Get the Decimal part of the string
    Dim DecimalPart As String = NumberString.Split("."c)(1)
    'If the number is already rounded to n decimal places, then return the number
    If DecimalPart.Length = places Then Return Number
    'Get whichever decimals are being rounded to
    Dim ToPlacePart As String = DecimalPart.Substring(0, places)
    'get the other part that will be compared
    Dim ComparePart As String = DecimalPart.Substring(places)
    'Create a midpoint to compare the compare part to
    Dim ControlMidPoint As Decimal = Decimal.Parse("1" & Replace(Space(ComparePart.Length), Space(1), "0")) / 2
    'Create the base result(Add the integer part to the decimal part that will stay)
    Dim Result As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(IntegerPart & "." & ToPlacePart)
    'Create an increment to add if the comparepart is greater than the mid point(ex 0.001, 0.01, 0.0000001)
    Dim AddNum As Decimal = Decimal.Parse("0." & Replace(Space(ToPlacePart.Count - 1), Space(1), "0") & "1")
    'If the comparepart was equal to or greater than the midpoint, then add the addpart to the base result and return it
    If Decimal.Parse(ComparePart) >= ControlMidPoint Then Return Result + AddNum
    'Just return the base result, because the compare part was smaller than the midpoint
    Return Result
End Function
```