# Datagridview Sum Column Error / vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, sum

Data sample: 20.50 and 20.00 
Total: 41.00

How can i get the exact number as 40.50 ? I can sum the column and show in label, however i can not solve the rounding problem.

```
If DataGridView1.RowCount > 1 Then
        Dim tutar As Integer = 0
        For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            total += Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value)
        Next
        Label1.Text = total.ToString("N2")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the variable `total` is an `Integer`, try changing your `total` variable to type `Double`.

somewhere in your code..

```
Dim total As Double = 0
```

and then change this:

```
If DataGridView1.RowCount > 1 Then
    Dim tutar As Integer = 0
    For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        total += Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value.tostring)
    Next
    Label1.Text = total.ToString()
End If
```

and if you want to do some rounding, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488850/prevent-math-round95-55555555-2-from-rounding-to-95-56-in-vb-net)

Comment: My mistake. There is no such thing 'tutar'. It's 'total'.

`        If DataGridView1.RowCount > 1 Then
            Dim total As Double = 0
            For index As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                total += Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView1.Rows(index).Cells(3).Value)
            Next
            Label1.Text = total.ToString()
        End If`

I tried that and didn't work.

Comment: it's okay.. just change `total` variable to `double`, or you may also use `decimal`.. depending on your needs.

Comment: Tried double or decimal. Both didn't work. Keep rounding the result.

Comment: I remove "=0"    Dim total As Double = 0   from that and it works. Thank you.