# Decimal truncating issue

Tags: c#, decimalformat

This is my issue.

> Math.Truncate(-18141235.58 * 100.0) / 100.0 
>   o/p:  -18141235.57

`.01` difference is coming. I have tried solutions as on ([Truncate Decimal number not Round Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329957/truncate-decimal-number-not-round-off?rq=1)) but doesnt work.

Issues resolves if I use 1000, but I want it to return 2 decimal places only, which might not be input value all time.

```
Math.Truncate(-18141235.58 * 1000.0) / 1000.0
```

Comment: Those are doubles, not decimals

Comment: Welcome to the exciting world of floating point! Floating point numbers are not exact. There will be issues like this. Try using the `decimal` datatype by adding the `m` suffix to your constants, e.g.: `Math.Truncate(-18141235.58m * 100.0m) / 100.0m` and see if that helps.