# Double value to scientific notation with fixed exponent C#

Tags: c#, double, notation, exponent

I am having value `double value = 1427799000;`

I would like to convert it to scientific notation where the values exponent must always 10^11 (E+11).

I have tried following but it is not working.

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("00.##E+11", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Output should be : `0.14 x 10^11 or 0.14E+11`

How to convert any double value to scientific notation with fixed exponent ? Here fixed exponent is 11.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011236/format-c-sharp-double-to-scientfic-notation-in-powers-with-multiples-of-three

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
double value = 1427799000;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("G2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

//output: 1.4E+09
```

[The General ("G") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx#GFormatString)

> The general ("G") format specifier converts a number to the most
> compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation, depending on the
> type of the number and whether a precision specifier is present.

**EDIT:** About your comment you can't display the scientific notation in your desirable way, it is not defined that way ! The coeficient must be greater or equal to 1 and less to 10.

**For number 1.23*10^11** ->[Article source](https://www.nyu.edu/pages/mathmol/textbook/scinot.html)

> **The first number 1.23 is called the coefficient. It must be greater than or equal to 1 and less than 10.**
>
> The second number is called the base . It must always be 10 in
> scientific notation. The base number 10 is always written in exponent
> form. In the number 1.23 x 10^11 the number 11 is referred to as the
> exponent or power of ten.

Comment: Thanks however I need the output to fixed exponent. Here exponent is 9, I want it to fixed 11. output should be `0.14E+11` How to do that?

Comment: @John Your way of representing is not correct and not by definition.

Comment: Thanks for the article source. I researched further more and found that my representation of 1427799000 `0.14E+11` is not correct. It should be `1.43E+09` or `1.43 x 10^9`.

Comment: @John you can mark the answer as correct in this case.