# Winform Datagridview Engineering Notation

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Anyone know how to get Engineering Notation in a cell in a datagridview similar to how excel displays with a ##0.0E+0 custom format?

`myDGV.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "E3"`

I got to here, but don't find anything to work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

I've tried every combination of E, 3, and ### I can think of.

Engineering notation examples:

0.1    => 100e-3 or 100m (not 1e-1)

1,000  => 1e3 or 1k

10,000 => 10e3 or 10k (not 1e4)

i.e. the powers of 10 always follow multiples of three (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation)

Comment: What about [The "E" and "e" custom specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SpecifierExponent)

Comment: This: `0.###E+0` should work ;)

Comment: You mention *engineering notation*: are you asking for the exponent to be a multiple of 3, so, milli, micro, nano, etc.?

Comment: Can you add a few sample inputs and outputs so that we can be sure of what you expect to see out, please?

Comment: Yes engineering notation, not scientific notation.
1,000 = 1e3
10,000 = 10e3 (not 1e4)
...
100,000 = 1e6

bonus points if e3 could be replaced k and and e6 could be replaced by M, etc.

Comment: There is nothing built into .NET to format numbers like that. You would have to write your own code to do that.

Comment: Bummer.  Engineering notation is so much better than scientific!  Oh welll. I'm willing to do that.  What are you thinking?  Display a string (instead of double), accept user entry and do the parsing / displaying myself in the backend?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Engineering notation in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808104/engineering-notation-in-c)