# Is there a way to round to, say, 3 significant figures in .net (f# specifically) BEFORE a decimal point?

Tags: .net, math, f#

In excel the function call "=round(12345,-3)" would resolve to "12000". That is, the -3 rounding parameter allows the application of significant figures before the decimal point.

Does anyone know of an easy way (i.e. existing library call rather than a writing a custom divide/round/multiply function) to do this in f#?

Math.Round (12345, -3) fails because the second value in the tuple is required to be positive.

Comment: For what its worth what you are describing is not rounding to 3 significant figures in a mathematical sense. 3 signifigant figures would be the first three figures in the number so in this case 12300.

Comment: As for the question the only thing I can think of would be a function that takes a power and does something like "(Math.Round(12345*(10^-3))/10^-3)" but I can't put that into F# syntax and I don't know if that is considered easy since it requires writing a whole new function and potentially introducing fun rounding errors, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374316/round-a-double-to-x-significant-figures-after-decimal-point/1925170#1925170

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ["G" standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString) to specify a number of significant digits. For example:

```
String.Format("{0:G3}", value)
```

Obviously this gives you a string as the output. Maybe that's what you were going to do with it anyway, or if not you can convert it back to a number with `Int32.Parse()` or similar.

There is also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374316/round-a-double-to-x-significant-figures-after-decimal-point/374470#374470), which although in C# should be fairly simple to convert as it's all .NET Framework method calls.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach.  possibly not the best for everyone.  Also actually rounds the number not a string format.

//      Rounding function that takes a significant figure count (sF)

```
let roundToSigFigs(x : float, sigFigs : byte) = 
    let absx = System.Math.Abs(x)
    System.Math.Round(0.5 + System.Math.Log10(absx))
    |> fun c -> float(c)-float(sigFigs)
    |> fun d  -> System.Math.Round(absx * 10.0**(-d)) * 10.0**d
    |> fun a -> a * float(System.Math.Sign(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Luca Bolognese implemented all the [Excel financial functions in F#](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/FinancialFunctions). Chances are this includes the rounding function you'd like to use, with the same behavior as Excel.