# Double to decimal not converting and rounding

Tags: c#

What is the best way to round double to two decimal places?

For example, I want to convert

```
3.45345323423423E+28
```

to

```
3.45
```

Comment: I have tried Math.Round(3.45345323423423E+28,2)..but its not working

Comment: Convert it in output, formate it with the `.ToString(string);` function.

Comment: Erm, are you use that you want to convert `3.45345323423423E+28` to `3.45`? There are quite some numbers in between and the difference between those decimals is huge :-)

Comment: I have done :- double doubl = Math.Round(3.45345323423423E+28,2); doubl.ToString("0.00")

Comment: As far as I'm aware, 3.45345323423423E+28 is actually 34534532342342300000000000000, so... you can't display that as 3.45, because it's... slightly larger than 3.45...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are aware that `3.45345323423423E+28` is a pretty large number and does not contain a decimal part?

(Stripping the [*scientific notation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), your number is 34,534,532,342,342,300,000,000,000,000 which is, of course, an integer).

If you want to round a number to 2 decimal places then use `Math.Round(value, 2);` But do be aware that your example number will not be changed.

If however, you want to round to 2 **significant figures**, then see this answer:
[Round a double to x significant figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374316/round-a-double-to-x-significant-figures)

Comment: Ok you are saying that this number does not contain a decimal part..rather it is merely a representation of a large number ?

Comment: Do you know what the "E+28" part of the number means?

Answer (score 1):

use Math.round

```
Math.Round (value, 2);
```

Rounds a number to a specified number of fractional digits double-precision floating-point value.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Math.Round(value, 2);
```

This will round up your value to 2 decimal places.

Store it in some variable or display it.

Comment: It is giving me same output as 3.45345323423423E+28

Comment: If going out of way  add `0.005` to number and convert to string via `variable.toString()` later take substring of 4 places from left and convert back to int by `parseInt` this will give you rounded value

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should consider using some other data type for such large number. Perhaps decimal. Because precision of double is only up to 15-16 digits.

If you still persist with double then you can use [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) here.

```
double db = 3.45345323423423E+28;
db = Math.Round(db, 2);
```

However, if you change your mind to switch to decimal then following should do the trick.

```
decimal d = 3.45345323423423E+28m;
d = decimal.Round(d, 2);
```

Comment: It is also giving me same output as 3.45345323423423E+28

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display it like this: 3.45E+28

Then you should do something like this:

```
double number = 3.45345323423423E+28;
string result = number.ToString("0.00E+00");
```

Hope this will help you in your quest.