# Converting Exponential Double value to int in C#

Tags: c#

I want to get the only that part which is before the point but I am unable to get it with every method. My value is 1.734565456765434E-06. I want to convert it into just 1

Comment: Do you know what number that is supposed to represent? It's not even close to 1.

Comment: I just want a number before point.

Comment: What about 2E+04  - should it be just 2? Some explanation of how you want to convert value would make question more concrete. Adding code you've tried will make question ok for SO.

Comment: Yes yes exactly if its 2E+04 i want just 2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374316/round-a-double-to-x-significant-figures should give you good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to [get the most significant digit of a number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437553/algorithm-to-find-greatest-significant-digit-of-long-integer).

```
var n = 1.734565456765434E-06;
var exp = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(n)); // -6
var result = Math.Floor(n / Math.Pow(10, exp)); // 1
```

This can be generalized to this:

```
var n = 1.734565456765434E-06;
var nDigits = 1; // 1 significant digit
var exp = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(n));
var result = Math.Floor(n / Math.Pow(10, exp + (1 - nDigits)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the first digit of your scientific representation, try this:

```
var number = 1.734565456765434E-06;
var numberString = number.ToString("E");
var firstDigitString = numberString.Substring(0, 1);
var firstDigit = int.Parse(firstDigitString);
```