# Round a decimal number to the first decimal position that is not zero

Tags: c#, .net, math, decimal, rounding

I want to shorten a number to the first significant digit that is not 0. The digits behind should be rounded.

Examples:

```
0.001 -> 0.001
0.00367 -> 0.004
0.00337 -> 0.003
0.000000564 -> 0.0000006
0.00000432907543029 ->  0.000004
```

Currently I have the following procedure:

```
if (value < (decimal) 0.01)
{
    value = Math.Round(value, 4);
}
```

Note:

- numbers will always be positive
- the number of significant digits will always be 1
- values larger 0.01 will always be rounded to two decimal places, hence the if < 0.01

As you can see from the examples above, a rounding to 4 Decimal places might not be enough and the value might vary greatly.

Comment: Have a look here: [round-a-double-to-x-significant-figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374316/round-a-double-to-x-significant-figures)

Comment: @AaronHayman: This is `decimal` rather than `double`, and the number of significant digits isn't necessarily known - I suspect the OP doesn't want to round 123.456 to 100 for example. (Although we'll see...)

Comment: What do you want to do for values that aren't between -1 and 1? For example, what would the result for 123.456 be?

Comment: The number of significant figures is surely one, from the description. I didn't say the link is the answer, but it does provides useful information to solving the problem

Comment: I was expecting some solution that uses `GetBits` to be faster, but (it seems that) the mantissa are not necessarily normalized, it's no easier than finding number of decimal places of the mantissa (still, some bit-scan-reverse hack may work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round a double to x significant figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374316/round-a-double-to-x-significant-figures)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would declare `precision` variable and use a  iteration multiplies that variable by `10` with the original value it didn't hit, that `precision` will add `1`.

then use `precision` variable be `Math.Round` second parameter.

I had added some modifications to the method which can support not only zero decimal points but also all decimal numbers.

```
static decimal RoundFirstSignificantDigit(decimal input) {

    if(input == 0)
       return input;

    int precision = 0;
    var val = input - Math.Round(input,0);
    while (Math.Abs(val) < 1)
    {
        val *= 10;
        precision++;
    }
    return Math.Round(input, precision);
}
```

I would write an extension method for this function.

```
public static class FloatExtension
{
    public static decimal RoundFirstSignificantDigit(this decimal input)
    {
        if(input == 0)
            return input;

        int precision = 0;
        var val = input - Math.Round(input,0);
        while (Math.Abs(val) < 1)
        {
            val *= 10;
            precision++;
        }
        return Math.Round(input, precision);
    }
}
```

then use like

```
decimal input = 0.00001;
input.RoundFirstSignificantDigit();
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xUNJbc)

**Result**

```
(-0.001m).RoundFirstSignificantDigit()                  -0.001
(-0.00367m).RoundFirstSignificantDigit()                -0.004
(0.000000564m).RoundFirstSignificantDigit()             0.0000006
(0.00000432907543029m).RoundFirstSignificantDigit()     0.000004
```

Comment: Note that this would require tweaking for negative values.

Comment: Math.Abs(val)<1?

Comment: @AccessDenied Yes I think just compare  absolute value

Comment: Why not use `Match.Abs(Match.Log10(input))` to get the requested precision?

Comment: @Hauleth because the OP input is `decimal` but `Math.Log10 ` only accept double :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.log10?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @D-Shih oh, I do not write C# much and I stumbled this question accidentally. Quick googling shows that you are right.

Comment: The current solution has aggregated floating-point rounding issues.  It would be better to create an integer loop variable, then each iteration multiply that variable by 10 and multiply that with the original value.  Also `ByFirstPrecision` is a horrible name - maybe something like `RoundFirstSignificantDigit`?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You method name more elegant than my original thanks

Comment: Very good approach, thank you! Note that it would go into an infinite loop with 0.

Comment: @user1106591 Thank for point out fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

Something like that ?

```
    public decimal SpecialRound(decimal value) 
    {
        int posDot = value.ToString().IndexOf('.'); // Maybe use something about cultural (in Fr it's ",")
        if(posDot == -1)
            return value;

        int posFirstNumber = value.ToString().IndexOfAny(new char[9] {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}, posDot);

        return Math.Round(value, posFirstNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = 0.000000564;

int cnt = 0;
bool hitNum = false;
var tempVal = value;
while (!hitNum)
{
    if(tempVal > 1)
    {
        hitNum = true;
    }
    else
    {
        tempVal *= 10;
        cnt++;
    }
}

var newValue = (decimal)Math.Round(value, cnt);
```

Answer (score 1):

code is from `R` but the algo should be obvious

```
> x = 0.0004932
> y = log10(x)
> z = ceiling(y)
> a = round(10^(y-z),1)
> finally = a*10^(z)
> finally
[1] 5e-04
```

### the following was basically already provided by Benjamin K

At the risk of being labelled a complete wacko,  I would cheerfully announce that  `regexp` is your friend.  Convert your number to a char string,  search for the location of the first char that is neither  "."  nor "0" , grab the char at that location and the next char behind it,  convert them to a number, round,  and (because you were careful), multiply the result by $10^{-(number of zeros you found between "." and the first number)}$

Comment: hmmm... looks like I was ninja'd by Benjamin K.   Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
    decimal RoundToFirstNonNullDecimal(decimal value)
    {
        var nullDecimals = value.ToString().Split('.').LastOrDefault()?.TakeWhile(c => c == '0').Count();
        var roundTo = nullDecimals.HasValue && nullDecimals >= 1 ? nullDecimals.Value + 1 : 2;
        return Math.Round(value, roundTo);
    }
```

**Result**

```
        Console.WriteLine(RoundToFirstNonNullDecimal(0.001m));                0.001
        Console.WriteLine(RoundToFirstNonNullDecimal(0.00367m));              0.004
        Console.WriteLine(RoundToFirstNonNullDecimal(0.000000564m));          0.0000006
        Console.WriteLine(RoundToFirstNonNullDecimal(0.00000432907543029m));  0.000004
        Console.WriteLine(RoundToFirstNonNullDecimal(0.12m));                 0.12
        Console.WriteLine(RoundToFirstNonNullDecimal(1.232m));                1.23
        Console.WriteLine(RoundToFirstNonNullDecimal(7));                     7.00
```

Comment: Your results don't match the criteria of "values larger 0.01 will always be rounded to two decimal places". The last two examples should be 1.23 and 7.00

Comment: you're right @GlenYates, for some reason I missed that requirement, I've edited my answer now.However this is a way slower solution than the accepted one, which I also upvoted!