# C# round a double to the first decimal place that makes sense

Tags: c#, math, decimal, rounding

I have an overloaded extension method which rounds either a decimal or double to N number of decimal places and it works perfectly.

```
public static class NumberExtensions
{
    public static string ToStringNDecimalPlaces(this double dbValue, int nDecimal)
    {
        return dbValue.ToString("N" + nDecimal);
    }

    public static string ToStringNDecimalPlaces(this decimal dbValue, int nDecimal)
    {
        return dbValue.ToString("N" + nDecimal);
    }
}
```

My question is, I want to create another called something like, "ToStringFirstDecimalPlace" or something like that which takes the decimal value and rounds it to the first logical decimal value after the 0s. Let me give some, this is how I would like the method to work:

e.g.

- 0.000345879 = 0.0003
- 0.019356 = 0.02
- 0.1 = 0.1

So it ignores the leading 0s and takes the nth to be the first logical number that makes sense instead of just rounding to 0.0 for example.

Comment: How do those zeroes 'not make sense' Are they 2nd class digits??

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "2nd class digits"?

Comment: Well, you want to 'ignore' them as they are 'not logical'..

Comment: I highly dobt you can find anything that rounds off that way, i would just write my own method doing that.

Comment: Yes, I want the leading zeros to be ignored when rounding to the first "logical" digit

Comment: Isn't that in part the question @HenrikGering?

Comment: It sounded like you were asking if you could find something to replace the "N" to make it round like you suggest. I do not think you can find that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round a decimal number to the first decimal position that is not zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440913/round-a-decimal-number-to-the-first-decimal-position-that-is-not-zero)

Comment: @Youssef13 you're a star! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well can't you count the number of zeroes and then format accordingly?

Example for positive values:

```
string result;
if(dbValue != 0)
{
    int count = 0;
    var copyDb = dbValue;
    while(copyDb < 1)
    {
        copyDb *= 10;
        count++;
    }
    result = dbValue.ToStringNDecimalPlaces(count);
}
else
{
    result = "0";
}
```

Comment: If the value is -5.049 for example, you're going to make the `result = "0"`, that's incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, that would need to be tweak a little (`Math.Abs`) for negative values, but OP only provided positive values as examples

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following function to achieve this:

```
public static string ToStringNDecimalPlacesIgnoreZeros(this double dbValue)
{

    var value = dbValue - Math.Floor(dbValue); // Get rid of integer digits
    int position = 0;
    while (value > 0 && Math.Floor(value) == 0)
    {
        value = value * 10;
        position += 1;
    }

    if (value == 0)
        return dbValue.ToString("N");
    else
        return dbValue.ToStringNDecimalPlaces( position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, assume that the input is between 0 and 1, inclusive. If not, subtract the integer part (and if negative, negate the remainder) before rounding the rest (this process can be reversed after the rounding is complete). Then, do something like this:

```
RountToFirstLogical(input)
1. place = 1
2. while place > input
3.    place = place / 10
4. input = round(input/place) * place
5. return input
```

Examples:

```
input=0.000345879
place=1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001
input/place = 3.45879
round(input/place) = 3
round(input/place) * place = 0.0003

input=0.019356
place=1, 0.1, 0.01
input/place = 1.9356
round(input/place) = 2
round(input/place)*place = 0.02

input=0.1
place=1, 0.1
input/place=1
round(input/place)=1
round(input/place)*place=0.1
```