# How do I specifically round to 9 numbers ignoring whether or not said number is significant or not

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, math

```
            if (Equation == "." || Equation == "")
                Answer = double.NaN;
            else
                Answer = (double)Equation.EvalNumerical();

            PreviousAnswerFlag = true;
            Equation = "";

            Answer = double.Parse(Answer.ToString("G7", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            OutputBox.Content = Answer;
```

I am building a calculator using WPF and because there is a set size to the window, the box used to output the answer cuts it off at a specific point (Around 9 numbers excluding negative and decimal symbols). Currently I am using a NuGet package to parse the Equation in string form into an answer and am using `.ToString()` to convert the number into its exponent but this happens at around 14 digits and cuts off when the answer goes above 999,999,999.

I need something that will convert the number to exponential form after nine digits or something that will round the number to 9 digits that counts zeros (as `Math.Round ()` does significant figures, the number is not always 9 digits long because it doesn't count initial zeros). I also need this to work regardless or positive, negative or decimal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round a double to x significant figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374316/round-a-double-to-x-significant-figures)

Comment: Decimal number in a computer are stored a base two number.  Converting from base two to base 10 give small errors like what you are seeing.  The is no easy way to fix these rounding errors as a number and often the easiest solution is to convert to a string and then do rounding.

Comment: @jdweng So something like converting the answer to a string and removing all digits after the 10th digit, then rounding the 9th digit using the 10th digit and shortening it to 9 digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
OutputBox.Content = string.Format("{0:E}", Answer);
```

Instead of doing all this complicated stuff, I have resorted to Just formatting the answer into Exponent form if the amount of digits exceeds nine.

Comment: One more little tip. Since you are making an application designed for «person» and not for «science», it is preferable to use `decimal` instead of `double`.