# Trim decimal digits

Tags: c++, trim, digits, rational-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Truncate a decimal value in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304011/truncate-a-decimal-value-in-c)

How can I truncate some of the decimal digits of a rational number so that it has only 6 digits? (For example `1.2345678909876` to `1.23456`)

Comment: The term you're looking for is *truncation*.

Comment: Fixed! Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Pseudocode: `(int)(num * 10 ^ ndecplaces) / (10 ^ ndecplaces)` should do the trick.

Comment: Are you printing these numbers to a standard stream?  If so, look at the precision() method for the output streams or the setprecision() manipulator.

Comment: Answer moved to comment: If you only care about a certain precision in the output, you can use [`setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes I was trying to write the code and thanks it looks like it works

Comment: I don't have to print the variables I have to use them in functions