# What is the best way to convert and truncate decimals of a C++ structure variable to a string? === SOLVED

Tags: visual-c++, type-conversion, structure

**How do you use variables within structures in C++?**

I'd like to move the data to a Winform textbox and to USB variables.

Tried several string conversion techniques, but I'm not referring to the structure element properly, I keep getting all sorts of errors.

I'd like to get to the contents that were just copied to FLIGHTDATA.

```
// Assign data to structure
     pObjData = (SIMCONNECT_RECV_SIMOBJECT_DATA*)pData;
     if (pData->dwID == SIMCONNECT_RECV_ID_SIMOBJECT_DATA && pObjData->dwRequestID == REQUEST_1)
         {
              FlightData = (Struct1*)&pObjData->dwData;
```

This is where FlightData is defined:

```
struct Struct1
{
    public:double RPM_Indicator;
//  double ADFMode;
};

//Struct1 LvarList;

SIMCONNECT_RECV_SIMOBJECT_DATA* pObjData = NULL;
SIMCONNECT_RECV* pData = NULL;
DWORD cbData = 0;
Struct1* FlightData = NULL;
bool bDone = false;
```

It's **RPM_Indicator** that interests me.

**1. What technique do I use to convert it to a string?
2. I'd also like to learn how to truncate *decimals*.**

Thanks!

Robert

---

**SOLUTION:**

It helps when you learn how to properly refer to the structure element, and to know how to convert types.  Thank you google.

```
int intEngineRPM = int(FlightData->RPM_Indicator);
this->tbRPM->Text = intEngineRPM.ToString();
```

Robert
:)

Comment: Your first question is not clear ? What do you want to convert to string ?  if you are talking about the RPM_Indicator which is double you can use `sprintf` with the desired format. Concerning the second question you might find the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304011/truncate-a-decimal-value-in-c)

Comment: I asked how do you use a variable that is within a structure 'cause I can't just use RPM_Indicator; it offers me choices, and none are the actual value.  
  
[img]https://i.imgur.com/XPpZ3ut.png[/img]
  
If I try to use RPM_Indicator alone, it generates an "E0020 error; undefined".  
  
I have to use what they put into Flight Data.  I've tried a multitude of variations of SPRINTF and other ways, none worked.  Unless I'm not using the proper parameters.   
   
[img]https://i.imgur.com/XuXLjks.png[/img]  
  
The value of 1126 is correct.  
  
Robert

Comment: UPDATE:  Thanks to Google I can now read a structure element into a Double, but I just moved the problem elsewhere cause I still can't do anything with the Double.  Can't display on GUI, can't convert to string...

[img]https://i.imgur.com/e69lLjq.png[/img]